# How to get data multi checkbox jquery show modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I want show data multi select checkbox and show data from database on modal bootstrap ?

**index(PHP)**

**Javascript Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#btnDetail").click(function()
    {
        $('#modalForm').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal',function()
        {
            var data = $("#data").val();
            $.post('page/user/detail_user.php',
            {
                id_data:$(this).attr(data)
            },
            function()
            {
                $('.modal-body').html(data);
            });
        });     
    });
});
</script>
```

**Data User**

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="3%" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="97%" align="center">NAME</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_users");
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
        {
        ?>
            <tr>
              <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="data[]" id="data[]" value='<?php echo $data['id']?>'></td>
              <td><?php echo $data['name']?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id='btnDetail' name='btnDetail'>Detail User</button>
```

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalForm" name='modalForm' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title blue" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Detail User(PHP)**

```
<?php
 $id = $_POST['id_data'];

$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_users WHERE id='$id'");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
?>
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th colspan='3'>
            Detail Data Users
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>NAME</td>
      <td>STATUS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $data['id']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['name']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['status']?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<?php
}
?>
```

Scenario : 
 When button Detail User is click run Jquery and value checkbox and then send to modal bootstrap, then post from jquery run code php to show result data from database on modal bootstrap.

Comment: Could you just summarize by stating what works and what doesn't. I am about sure to know what you want, but for the sake of people who help others, it is a good practice to have (if possible) well defined question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, my question is how to display data from database to modal bootstrap on the checkbox selected?, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are hints to fix the problem :

1. ID in HTML shall be unique. (Not as the id "data[]" for all checkboxes)
2. `this` is contextual. So, when you use `this` in a bootstrap function, it probably (I would have to ensure) doesn't mean the previous jQuery function.
3. You should manage retrieving the values of all the checked boxes.
4. The PHP code should use the `IN` operator for the ID instead.

Comment: So where should I start coding fix it ?

Comment: Start by correcting what I pointed out. I have to sleep now, middle of the night here. Try to locate each point with your current code. Try something before asking and show me what you have tried.

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: yeah, my problem solve
var data = [];
    $.each($("input[name='data']:checked"), function()
    {            
     data.push($(this).val());
    });

Comment: So did it help ? If yes, you should consider accepting the answer.